# What is the most commonly considered measure on $2^\omega$?

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question

The product measure is the most common example I've come across (i.e. the product measure of Bernoulli(1/2) with itself $\omega$ times), but I don't know if there is a Lebesgue-like measure (or something else) that is more commonly used. For my purposes, it REALLY doesn't matter what the specific properties of the measure are. I'm just looking for something to mention as a "standard example".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the product measure of $\{0,1\}$ with the $\mu(\{0\}) = \mu(\{1\})= \frac12$ measure is the standard one. It's in fact also the Lebesgue measure if we consider $2^\omega$ is the middle third Cantor set $C$, and renormalise to $\mu(C)=1$ ( think relativised measure is used for that). So IMO it's the natural choice.

Comment: I appreciate the brevity and straightforwardness of your answer :)

Comment: Humm... The Lebesgue measure of  the middle third Cantor set $C$ is zero. How would you renormalise to make it $\mu(C)=1$? Relativised measue will give you a null measure.

Comment: Right...what if, instead of removing thirds at each stage, you remove the middle 1/2^n at stage n? Then does Henno's answer make sense?

Comment: @Ramiro one way is to pull back the measure on $[0,1]$ over the Cantor function.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok. But pull back is not renormalisation. The resulting measure would be very different from the Lebesgue measure. It would miss important properties of Lebesgue measure, such as translation invariance. 

The fact is that the product measure of $2^\omega$ is not a renormalised version of Lebesgue measure of $2^\omega$ considered as the  the middle third Cantor set $C$.

Comment: @Ramiro that pull back I described has the same effect as a relative renormalisation; eg the measure of $[0,\frac13]\cap C$ becomes $\frac12$ etc.pullback avoids division by 0 problems.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The pull back  measure over the Cantor function is a nice pullback measure, with nice properties. No question about it. But it is not  true that it "has the same effect as a relative renormalisation". Why? first of all, the middle third Cantor set has Lebesgue measure zero and any relative renormalisation will keep it with measure 0.

Comment: @Ramiro but half the set has half the measure. So the proportion of the parts remains.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I agree, but that is not enough to call it a renormalization of the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Ramiro There is some construction in probability theory when we condition on an event of zero probability. This can also define a measure without the zero-division problem.

Comment: @Ramiro This is an interesting discussion, but just to check, do you agree with HB's original statement that the product measure is the most common one to use on $2^\omega$?

Comment: @AriHerman yes, for sure.

Comment: @Ramiro Okay, thanks!

Comment: @AriHerman Okay? Thanks?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You wrote: "There is some construction in probability theory when we condition on an event of zero probability". Yes, I know. But that is not relative renormalization of the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Ramiro it sort of is though. The name is just different.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma well, names and definitions are essential. But if  you decide to call "renormalisation" a broader class of methods to build measures, then a lot of things will become renormalisation.

Comment: @AriHerman  To be clear, I agree that the product measure is the most common one to use on $2^\omega$. However this measure in not a relative renormalisation of the Lebesgue measure of the middle third Cantor set (which is zero).

Comment: @Ramiro Yes, that is how I understood your comment.